# How to use pandas built-in functions to get dataframes for two month ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a date column, which contains the 'month', and I need to create two dataframes from this dataframe. the first one will contain all the listings for which the month values are from 1 to 6, and the second dataframe will contain all the listings for which the month values are from 7 to 12. How can I do this? I have tried this

```
train_set = data.loc(data['DateTime'] <= 6)
test_set = data.loc(data['DateTime'] > 6)
```

But, I am getting the following error :

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

Why might I be getting this error? And what is a way that I can achieve what I am trying to do? The column 'DateTime' contains only the month value that I extracted from the original data which was in python datetime format.

Comment: You need to use square brackets for `loc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with correct format of `loc[]`.

```
train_set = data.loc[data['DateTime'] <= 6]
test_set = data.loc[data['DateTime'] > 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to `loc`, you can as well achieve the result using:

```
train_set = data[data['DateTime'] <= 6]
test_set = data[data['DateTime'] > 6]
```